# title page "sharpness" (for lack of a better word)

Tags: fonts, titles, kerning

I've noticed a very small yet perceptible difference between the title pages I produce and some that I've stumbled across.

Using the standard `\maketitle` command and filling in the standard author, date, abstract fields, I produce something that looks like
[this.](http://people.bu.edu/blipman/Papers/current.pdf)

However, I've come across many papers with titles that look more like [this.](http://people.bu.edu/jnoor/jnoor/Research_files/TemptationSocialPref.pdf)

You'll notice that in the latter case, the kerning is a bit smaller and the font seems a bit thicker.  However, the font isn't bold (I tried that) and I've seen this often enough that I'm quite sure it's not a manual kerning or font weight edit, but rather just a command or package I'm not aware of.

Comment: @cfr For the sake of closure, wanna transform that comment into an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Answer (score 3):

The style you prefer was prepared using different software. More specifically, it probably used LaTeX or TeX to output the `.dvi` and then definitely used Acrobat Distiller to produce the pdf. In contrast, yours was created with pdfTeX. Moreover, although I don't know enough about Distiller to say, the result is that the other document uses truetype fonts whereas yours uses type1. Finally, some of the fonts are different even though both documents predominately use Computer Modern. Look at the documents' properties and fonts in your PDF viewer for details.